# python3 pyvenv does not deactivate on macosx

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

I have created a virtualenv with the Python3.4.1, but when I try to execute `deactivate` on the console i receive the error message `bash: deactivate: command not found` , I have different versions of Python installed, including the python 2.6, 2.7, 3.3 and the 3.4.1 in this question.

How can I deactivate the virtualenv?

Note: I can actually have two virtualenv open together, presenting itself in the command line as `(projecta)(projectb) user@computer $`

Comment: There is likely something wrong with your setup. Have you tried virtualenvwrapper? It makes dealing with virtualenv a bit easier.

Comment: I have it installed, but to be honest I haven't got to the point where I got to use it.